# How to auto increment a set of rows while inserting with the same value, safely?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's take this table :

```
 id | ownerid |
----+---------+
  1 |      98 |
  1 |      99 |
  2 |     100 |
  2 |     101 |
  2 |     102 |
  3 |     103 |
  3 |     104 |
```

id column has AUTO_INCREMENT constraint but has not a UNIQUE constraint.
**I want to insert a set of rows as the following :**

```
INSERT INTO table
VALUES
    (DEFAULT, 105),
    (DEFAULT, 106),
    (DEFAULT, 107);
```

But it will result in

```
 id | ownerid |
----+---------+
  4 |     105 |
  5 |     106 |
  6 |     107 |
```

However, it need to be

```
 id | ownerid |
----+---------+
  4 |     105 |
  4 |     106 |
  4 |     107 |
```

Also, I want to avoid concurrency requests using AUTO_INCREMENT and not MAX(something).

Comment: I'm confused.  Postgres doesn't support `auto_increment`, as far as I know.

Comment: What's the database? AUTO_INCREMENT is usually available in MySQL or MariaDB.

Comment: Use a sequence instead. That's what sequences were made for. They are much more flexible than identity columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I used SERIAL actually, but it's UNIQUE so i'd like something similar to SERIAL but not UNIQUE. Or maybe just something without any constraint but being sure that requests will not overlap

Comment: @TheImpaler Idk what it is, I'm gonna check that, thanks !

Comment: `SERIAL`, `IDENTITY`, and `SEQUENCE` were designed to produce **unique** values. They may be sequential or not and that cannot be assured. Why do you want them to be serial?

Comment: I need to be sure that a  "row set" insert will not occur in confusing its id with another "row set". And the ids of a row set are just an incrementation of the last id value. EDIT: but actually it might be a XY problem, I'm kind of stuck on this